# Is there any way to size divs in css like android view weights?

Tags: html, css

In android you can make 3 vertical views fill up their parent each with a different size by using weights.  I have 3 divs on my html page, the two that need to always be at the bottom are both 40px tall, and then there will be one above those that need to fill in the rest of the space of the parent div.  Is there any way to do this without using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `display:table-row` for the 3 divs and set the height as `40px` for the two at the bottom.

Using `display:tablexxx` is quite often delicate, especially in a cross browser fashion, so I'm building a demonstration on how you could have this cover the whole page :

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/EYAXuZo/13/)

HTML of the demo :

```
 <div id=w>
  <div id=a>
    <div id=b>B</div>
    <div id=c>C</div>
    <div id=d>D</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS of the demo :

```
#w {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0; left:0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
#a{
  display: table;
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
#b {
  display: table-row;
  background: red;
}
#c {
  display: table-row;
  background: yellow;
  height:40px;
}
#d {
  display: table-row;
  background: green;
  height:40px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I did not know about this display type.  I will choose as best answer as soon as it lets me.